# Swfit- Check whether current time is between two time string

Tags: ios, swift

How to check if the current time is between two-time strings in the following format.
`HH:MM AM/PM`
say if

```
startTime = "10:30 AM" 
endTime = "06:30 PM"
```

how to check if `currentTime()` value is in between start and end times?

Comment: Have you tired to get the Unix Time stamp equivalent of the date+time and then compare all three values. The time stamp shouldn't be below the start time and above the end time

Comment: I get the start and end date from API so Unix timestamp is not possible

Comment: Then you can just use the normal swift feature to compare time stamps....I will give an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the date formatter `defaultDate` for today, parse the date strings, create a `DateInterval` with the start and end date and check if it contains now `Date()`:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let today: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        return dateFormatter
        
    }()
}
```

---

```
func checkIfCurrentTimeIsBetween(startTime: String, endTime: String) -> Bool {
    guard let start = Formatter.today.date(from: startTime),
          let end = Formatter.today.date(from: endTime) else {
        return false
    }
    return DateInterval(start: start, end: end).contains(Date())
}
```

---

```
let startTime = "10:30 AM"
let endTime = "06:30 PM"
checkIfCurrentTimeIsBetween(startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)   // true
```

Comment: I like the trick of a `today` formatter that defaults to times on the current day. Using a DateInterval to check if the current time is between the start and end times seems a little silly, however. For the last several OS releases, Date objects have been Comparable, so you could just say `if now >= start && now <= end`

Comment: @DuncanC I like to favor readability. I could also use a date range and pattern matching operator and return `start..<end ~= Date()` but OP seems pretty new to Swift

Comment: I personally loathe the pattern match operator as far as readability (or rather lack of readability.)

Comment: I have a scenario that I want to show availability which can be from 11:00 AM today to 03:00 AM tomorrow and then I want to show if user is available or not. How will be that workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swift's `Dateformatter()` to encode and compare dates:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
dateFormatter.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

let startTimeFormatted = dateFormatter.today.date(from: startTime)
let endTimeFormatted = dateFormatter.today.date(from: endTime)

//Now you can compare the two, e.g.

if startTimeFormatted > currentDate() && currentDate() < endTimeFormatted{
    return true
}
```

Comment: There is a few issues with your code. it should be `hh` instead of `h`. You should use locale "en_US_POSIX". And the resulting dates would be in January 1st, 2000 not today.

Comment: There is no `today` instance property on `DateFormatter`. `dateFormatter.today` is wrong. Just use plain `dateFormatter.whatever`. You are still using the wrong locale. You should always try to compile your code before posting an answer.

Comment: And I forgot to mention you should set the locale BEFORE setting the `dateFormat` property.