# Swift 5: Calculate current time is between 2 times

Tags: swift, datetime, timestamp, nsdate

I am not good at Swift so I would like to know how to calculate the current time is between two times.

I got the following response from the backend.
`{"workHours":"M-F 9:00 - 18:00"}`

From the above string, how to write a class/struct(or another best way) to validate today's current time is in the described time range(`"M-F 9:00 - 18:00"`)?

```
public final class DateValidator {
    let startTime: Date?
    let endTime: Date?
    
    func isInRange() -> Bool {
        // write modules here
        // How to validate
    }
    
    public init(dateString: String) {
        // dateString should be "M-F 9:00 - 18:00"
        // Extract startTime and endTime from dateString
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64160800/swfit-check-whether-current-time-is-between-two-time-string

Comment: You don't want to interpret the weekday?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your interest. The perfect answer is to check weekday too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the DateComponentsFormatter

```
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
dcf.unitsStyle = .full
```

Set up ordinary date formatter

```
let df = ISO8601DateFormatter()
df.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withDashSeparatorInDate]
```

Perform formatting

```
if let future = df.date(from: "2019-04-29"), let diff = dcf.string(from: Date(), to: future) {
    print(diff)
}
```

Output is

3 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes, 9 seconds